# DerivativeFilter and List Manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I have a list with about 8000 pairs of values like

```
      List ={{0,1},{1.2,4},{1.6,8},{2.11111,10},...}
```

and I want to have a list with the derivate of the function using DerivativeFilter[ ] upon the entries.
To do so, i want to extract just the second value of the list, i.e.
obtain

```
        List2= {1,4,8,10,....}
```

I didnt find any solution to my problem to do that easily.

Also: Is there an easier way to gain the derivate? And another question:
How could I act with an operation only on the first or second variable of the pair, for example

```
          List3={{0,f[1]},{1.f[2,4]},{1.6,f[8]},{2.11111,f[10]},...}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) is a built-in command - don't use it as a name for user-defined variables! All MMA built-in commands are upper case (there's also [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) and [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html?q=D) and many more). It's safest to **always** use lower case user-defined names.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = {{0, 1}, {1.2, 4}, {1.6, 8}, {2.11111, 10}};
list2 = list1[[All, 2]]
```

> {1, 4, 8, 10}

```
list3 = MapAt[f, list1, {{All, -1}}]
```

> {{0, f[1]}, {1.2, f[4]}, {1.6, f[8]}, {2.11111, f[10]}}

Also

```
list2b = Last /@ list1
```

> {1, 4, 8, 10}

```
list3b = list1; list3b[[All, -1]] = f /@ list3b[[All, -1]]; list3b
```

> {{0, f[1]}, {1.2, f[4]}, {1.6, f[8]}, {2.11111, f[10]}}